# Ruby C Extension - TypeError on TypedData_Get_Struct call that is no type error

Tags: c++, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I am working on a Ruby C/C++ Extension and thus far it has been going quite well. However I came across an error that I don't know what to do about it.

I have defined the following ruby data types:

```c
static const rb_data_type_t SmartLib_File_type = {
  "SmartLib::File",
  {0, SmartLib_File_free, SmartLib_File_size,},
  0, 0,
  RUBY_TYPED_FREE_IMMEDIATELY,
};

static const rb_data_type_t SmartLib_Plotter_type = {
  "SmartLib::Plotter",
  {0, SmartLib_Plotter_free, SmartLib_Plotter_size,},
  0, 0,
  RUBY_TYPED_FREE_IMMEDIATELY,
};
```

both those data types are being wrapped by their corresponding C++ classes and represented by Ruby classes:

```c
// SmartLib::File
VALUE SmartLib_File_alloc(VALUE self) {
    /* allocate */
    SmartLib::TransformableFile *data = new SmartLib::TransformableFile();

    /* wrap */
    return TypedData_Wrap_Struct(self, &SmartLib_File_type, data);
}

// SmartLib::Plotter
VALUE SmartLib_Plotter_alloc(VALUE self) {
    /* allocate */
    SmartLib::Plotter *data = new SmartLib::Plotter();

    /* wrap */
    return TypedData_Wrap_Struct(self, &SmartLib_Plotter_type, data);
}
```

In order to make unwrapping of those C/C++ data easier, I have also two macros defined to help with this:

```c
#define UNWRAP_SMART_FILE(obj, fp) \
    SmartLib::TransformableFile* fp;\
    TypedData_Get_Struct((obj), SmartLib::TransformableFile, &SmartLib_File_type, (fp));

#define UNWRAP_SMART_PLOTTER(obj, pp) \
    SmartLib::Plotter* pp;\
    TypedData_Get_Struct((obj), SmartLib::Plotter, &SmartLib_Plotter_type, (pp));
```

Now, I have a Ruby method `plot` in the `SmartLib::Plotter` class, with the following definition:

```c
VALUE SmartLib_Plotter_plot(VALUE self, VALUE rb_oFile, VALUE rb_sTemplatePath) {
  UNWRAP_SMART_PLOTTER(self, smartPlotter);
  UNWRAP_SMART_FILE(rb_oFile, smartFile);

  // do stuff

  return self;
}
```

which is callable from Ruby like so:

```rb
sf = SmartLib::File.new(file_path)
p  = SmartLib::Plotter.new

p.plot(sf, template_path)
```

The problem arises on the `UNWRAP_SMART_FILE(rb_oFile, smartFile);` line int he `plot` method, so when the corresponding C/C++ data gets unwrapped. Ruby throws an exception:

```
TypeError:
       wrong argument type SmartLib::File (expected SmartLib::File)
```

In other areas of the code the call to `UNWRAP_SMART_FILE` always works as expected. Also the error message clearly doesn't make sense?

Any help is kindly appreciated!

Comment: `rb_oFile` aka `sf` probably doesn't meet the `RB_TYPE_P(rb_oFile, T_DATA)` or `RTYPEDDATA_P(rb_oFile)` requirements of `TypedData_Get_Struct`. Try renaming `"SmartLib::File"` (e.g. to `"smartlib-file"`) and then the error message may make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried it, but I get the same weird error message `wrong argument type smartlib-file (expected smartlib-file)`

Comment: Can you post the return values too? There's another check equivalent to `rb_typeddata_inherited_p(RTYPEDDATA_TYPE(rb_oFile), &SmartLib_File_type)` but currently I can't think of a reason it'd fail. All three should return a nonzero value.

Comment: Sure, here they are:
`RB_TYPE_P(rb_oFile, T_DATA) --> 1`,
`RTYPEDDATA_P(rb_oFile) --> 1`,
`rb_typeddata_inherited_p(RTYPEDDATA_TYPE(rb_oFile), &SmartLib_File_type) --> 0`

Comment: I've also compared now `RTYPEDDATA_TYPE(rb_oFile)` and `&SmartLib_File_type` and the memory addresses are different: `0x10feb8190` vs `0x10feb8220` which explains why the `rb_typeddata_inherited_p` check fails.

Comment: Is the definition of `SmartLib_File_type` in a header? It sounds like that might be the cause. Adding the respective filename to the top of your code excerpts as a comment (e.g. `// plotter.cpp`) would help.

Comment: Thank you for your help and guidance! Your guess was correct, I had the definition in the header, which caused `SmartLib_File_type` to be defined multiple times. I fixed it and now the address is constant across the program. Total oversight of mine.